# More concise syntax

Tags: workflow, formula

I'm trying to develop a scoring system for a survey and am having trouble making the syntax as parsimonious as possible in order to stay under the character limits when I start compiling formulas.

I've looked on Google and on these forums, along with the documentation, but I'm having trouble finding an answer. I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to code the following:

```
CASE(Close_to_my_ideal__c,
 "1. Strongly disagree",1,
 "2. Disagree", 2,
 "3. Neither agree nor disagree", 3,
 "4. Agree", 4, "5. Strongly agree", 5, 0) + 
CASE(Important_things_I_want__c, 
 "1. Strongly disagree",1,
 "2. Disagree", 2,
 "3. Neither agree nor disagree", 3,
 "4. Agree", 4,
 "5. Strongly agree", 5, 0) + 
CASE(Satisfied_with_my_life__c,
 "1. Strongly disagree", 1,
 "2. Disagree", 2,
 "3. Neither agree nor disagree", 3,
 "4. Agree", 4,
 "5. Strongly agree", 5, 0)
```

I have several scales that have items scored on the same Likert-type scale, so it would be nice not to have to waste characters repeating the scale scores each time.

I have received advice to use Workflow Rule Field Updates to set actual data fields for the 'contributing values', then use a formula to evaluate those 'contributing values'.

However, I have tried to implement this and am not sure how to do so.  Essentially, I am wondering if there's a way to not have to repeat the scale scores for each case.

I thank you all in advance for your help/advice.

Comment: are you hitting char limit ?

Comment: If you build the data model such that a survey had questions and questions had answers and each answer had text and a value, then built a results object that linked to the answer. You could pull all the information in via formulas instead of having to go through all of this. Something like this is where the Data Model is very important.

Answer (score 6):

Using your exact list options, you could do this:

```
VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(Close_to_my_ideal__c), 1))+
VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(Important_things_I_want__c), 1))+
VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(Satisfied_with_my_life__c), 1))
```

Convert the picklist value to text, then take the left-most character, and convert it to a number, then add them together.

Comment: This is going to break on `null` though perhaps?

Comment: I just did a quick check myself, and in the event of an empty picklist, you just get an empty formula value... you don't get ERROR! though, which could be considered the correct behavior?

Comment: If you want to ensure it evaluates to a number each time, you could try adding a "0" to each value

Comment: ie VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(Close_to_my_ideal__c) + "0", 1))

Comment: Actually, I think `VALUE(LEFT(NULLVALUE(TEXT(Close_to_my_ideal__c),'0'),1))` should avoid any null issues. It may also depend on the use of "treat blanks as zeroes".

Comment: Yeah, I haven't actually tried it on a picklist - I just substituted in some text to test. The rationale was to avoid any extra function calls.